# Setting up a simple webservice using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to set up a simple webservice using asp.net. Here's my code behind file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyFirstWebServiceApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public String MyFirstWebMethod(String firstName, String lastName)
        {
            //return "How are you " + firstName + " " + lastName + "?";
            return String.Format("How are you {0} {1}?", firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

the solution builds successfully . However when I run it, and then try to invoke it, it doesn't display the expected XML and only shows the following message

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Here's a screenshot of what I get
http://i45.tinypic.com/2roixvr.png

Comment: How are you invoking it?

Comment: well Im just running it (hitting F5) and it opens a new browser pane. I was basically following this link http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UPX38CfO9vk

Comment: OK, where if the document tree you are referring to?  post a screen shot or the text.  If this is the built-in .asmx default web page, it may be missing something.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of the page im getting after hitting invoke http://i45.tinypic.com/2roixvr.png. And  yes, Im using the default built in .asmx file  with the following content '<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" Class="Service" %>'

Comment: @LeorA;  The Service1.asmx folder only has code behind file.  Here is a screenshot of the the directory structure in VS http://i49.tinypic.com/14kfmup.jpg

Comment: Can you navigate to the .asmx URL in your browser (without the /HelloWorld path), and then what do you get?

Comment: @LeorA : I get this  http://tinypic.com/r/5l0txi/6

Comment: Why do you think you should get anything different? This is what the browser shows for XML with no stylesheet. Try using "View Source" to see what got sent to the browser.

Comment: Also, why are you working with ASMX web services? They're all but obsolete, and shouldn't be used for new development. All development of new web services or clients should use WCF.

Comment: Well, that page looks correct.  Strange.

Comment: Well I just figured that it works correctly with IE, the issue seemed to be with Chrome I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with Firefox, then press ctrl+shift+J, you will get error console, find the error from it.